# how to change shell on amazon EC2 linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I installed c shell using the `sudo yum install tcsh` command on my brand new amazon EC2 instance, but I'm not sure if it's actually working, since the `echo $SHELL` command always returns `/bin/bash`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
[ec2-user]$ which csh
/bin/csh
[ec2-user]$ sudo csh
[root]# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[root]# sudo chsh
Changing shell for root.
New shell [/bin/bash]: /bin/csh
Shell changed.
[root]# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[root]#
```

Answer (score 7):

Amazon Linux 2 doesn't come with `chsh` installed. So before you can run `chsh`, you must first install it.

`sudo yum install util-linux-user`

If you want to change the shell for the account you're currently logged in as (e.g., for the `ec2-user` or other non-root user that you login with), then you can run `chsh` interactively. There's no need to use `sudo` (as another answer said).

To change the shell for someone other than yourself (e.g., root, another user), you do need to use `sudo`.

There is also no need to reboot. The change will take affect the next time you login. As a matter of safety, you might want to login from a different window (i.e., stay logged in in one window, while testing the shell change in a different window), in case you typo something and can't get back in.

Comment: Everything is working fine but it now asks password for ec2-user to change the shell. But I have never set a password. What should I do ?

Comment: Root can always set attributes for anyone. So, since `sudo` works, you can just run `sudo chsh ec2-user`. It won't prompt you for ec2-user's password. Likewise, if you want to change the ec2-user's password, root can do that, too. Just run `sudo passwd ec2-user`.

Comment: This `sudo yum install util-linux-user` does not work as I get the error `No package util-linux-user available.`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

I wanted to change from bash to zsh, but you can use `which csh` instead. You might need to restart the instance after.

Comment: This command runs 4 programs when 1 would do. The `which` command will tell you where the zsh command is, but if that's not what's in `/etc/shells` the command will fail. There's no need to use `sudo` to change your own shell. There's no need to run a program `whoami` when you can just type `$USER` and get it from the environment. They should just type `chsh` and hit enter, but of course after they install `chsh`, which isn't installed on Amazon Linux 2.